# Error registration form 21

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to create a registration form, to put the details in the databaase but when i try this script out, i get the error.
Fatal error: Call to undefined function now()
Could you poeple help me out with this problem, really confused about the error.

```
//Defineer functie
function error($link)
{
header('Refresh: 3; url=' . $link.php . '');
}

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') // Controle of er op de knop is     geklikt.
{
include_once 'config.php'; // Connectie db.

if(!empty($_POST['gebruikersnaam']) AND !empty($_POST['password']) AND !empty($_POST['passwordc']) AND !empty($_POST['mail'])) // Controle op invoeren
{
    if(($_POST['password']) == ($_POST['passwordc'])) // Controle of controle pw overeenkomt met echte pw.
    {

        include_once 'uwx3g.php';            // Connectie met salt page.
        $gebruikersnaam    = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['gebruikersnaam']); //Data veilig maken voor sql injectie d.m.v. mysql_real.....
        $password        = sha1(salt($_POST['password'])); //sha1 hash van pass. Inclusief salt.
        $mail            = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mail']);
        $sql = ("SELECT gebruikersnaam FROM gebruikers WHERE gebruikersnaam='". $gebruikersnaam . "'"); // Controle op gebruikersnaam, zo ja een 1 else en 0 (zie controle bij de volgende if)
        $uitvoer = mysql_query($sql);        //($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get))

        $controle = mysql_num_rows($uitvoer);

        if($controle == 0) // Als uitvoer is 0 registreren.
        {
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (id, gebruikersnaam, password, mail, datum) VALUES ('','" . $gebruikersnaam . "', '" . $password . "', '" . $mail . "', '" . now() . "')"); // Gebruiker in db plaatsen.
            header('Refresh: 4; url=login.php');
            exit ('U bent succesvol aangemeld, u kunt nu inloggen.');
        }
        else
        {
            header('Refresh: 2; url=registreren.php');
            exit ('Verkeerde gebruikersnaam of wachtwoord.');        // Negatieve melding van ingevoerde gegevens.
        }    
    }
    else
    {
        error(registreren.php);
        exit ('De ingevoerde gegevens kloppen niet, u heeft het controle wachtwoord verkeerd ingevuld.');  // Negatieve melding van ingevoerde gegevens.
    }
}
else
{
    error(registreren.php);
    exit ('De ingevoerde gegevens kloppen niet, niet alles is ingevuld.');  // Negatieve melding van ingevoerde gegevens.
}



}
else
{
error(registreren.php);
exit ('U bent op de verkeerde pagina gekomen, U wordt doorverwezen.');
}

?>
```

Comment: NOW() is a SQL function now a PHP function, so you would have to remove the (".) before and (.") after now(), so the script acren't trying to calll a PHP function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NOW()` is a MySQL function, not PHP. So it must be part of your SQL string:

```
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (id, gebruikersnaam, password, mail, datum) VALUES ('','" . $gebruikersnaam . "', '" . $password . "', '" . $mail . "', NOW())"); // Gebruiker in db plaatsen.
```